# Error deploying WAR file on JBOSS EAP 6.4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jboss

I am developing a standalone application using JBOSS Developer Studio v9.0.0.GA, Spring and Hibernate. Previously it was working fine, i am able to deploy to WAR file to the EAP and managed to get the webservice working. But now I encounter error while trying to do that.

Here's the console output:

```
13:34:40,984 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
13:34:41,089 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
13:34:41,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) starting
13:34:41,778 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found fwd-PMAP.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called fwd-PMAP.war.dodeploy
13:34:41,792 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO Version 3.0.13.GA-redhat-1
13:34:41,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:34:41,796 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.13.GA-redhat-1
13:34:41,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:34:41,841 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.4.Final-redhat-1
13:34:41,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
13:34:41,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.31.Final-redhat-1)
13:34:41,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:34:41,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013371: Activating Security Subsystem
13:34:41,884 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
13:34:41,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:34:41,916 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:34:41,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:34:41,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:34:42,005 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013370: Current PicketBox version=4.1.1.Final-redhat-1
13:34:42,102 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
13:34:42,105 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
13:34:42,125 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "fwd-PMAP.war" (runtime-name: "fwd-PMAP.war")
13:34:42,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "sqljdbc42.jar" (runtime-name: "sqljdbc42.jar")
13:34:42,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\deployments
13:34:42,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
13:34:42,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
13:34:42,151 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:34:42,160 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.4.Final-redhat-1
13:34:42,304 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.2)
13:34:42,314 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/SQLServer]
13:34:43,203 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for pmap
13:34:43,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for arba
13:34:43,433 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "fwd-PMAP.war" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
13:34:43,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'fwd-PMAP.war#arba'
13:34:43,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'fwd-PMAP.war#pmap'
13:34:43,502 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final-redhat-1}
13:34:43,505 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.18.Final-redhat-2}
13:34:43,506 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
13:34:43,506 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
13:34:43,516 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: arba
    ...]
13:34:43,516 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: pmap
    ...]
13:34:43,529 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#pmap": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#pmap": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pmap] class or package not found
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pmap] class or package not found
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1431)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1058)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fwd.pmap.domain.Campaign from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @1e89d68 (finder: local module finder @1192d32 (roots: C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules,C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base\.overlays\BZ1281963,C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1348)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1420)
    ... 11 more

13:34:43,529 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#arba": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#arba": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: arba] class or package not found
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: arba] class or package not found
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1431)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1058)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fwd.pmap.domain.PMAPEtrekWorking from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @1e89d68 (finder: local module finder @1192d32 (roots: C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules,C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base\.overlays\BZ1281963,C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1348)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1420)
    ... 11 more

13:34:43,533 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "fwd-PMAP.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"fwd-PMAP.war#arba\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"fwd-PMAP.war#arba\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: arba] class or package not found
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: arba] class or package not found
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fwd.pmap.domain.PMAPEtrekWorking from [Module \"org.hibernate:main\" from local module loader @1e89d68 (finder: local module finder @1192d32 (roots: C:\\jbdevstudio\\runtimes\\jboss-eap\\modules,C:\\jbdevstudio\\runtimes\\jboss-eap\\modules\\system\\layers\\base\\.overlays\\BZ1281963,C:\\jbdevstudio\\runtimes\\jboss-eap\\modules\\system\\layers\\base))]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"fwd-PMAP.war#pmap\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"fwd-PMAP.war#pmap\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pmap] class or package not found
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pmap] class or package not found
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fwd.pmap.domain.Campaign from [Module \"org.hibernate:main\" from local module loader @1e89d68 (finder: local module finder @1192d32 (roots: C:\\jbdevstudio\\runtimes\\jboss-eap\\modules,C:\\jbdevstudio\\runtimes\\jboss-eap\\modules\\system\\layers\\base\\.overlays\\BZ1281963,C:\\jbdevstudio\\runtimes\\jboss-eap\\modules\\system\\layers\\base))]"
}}
13:34:43,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS015859: Deployed "sqljdbc42.jar" (runtime-name : "sqljdbc42.jar")
13:34:43,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS015859: Deployed "fwd-PMAP.war" (runtime-name : "fwd-PMAP.war")
13:34:43,557 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#arba": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#arba": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: arba] class or package not found
      service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#pmap": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#pmap": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pmap] class or package not found

13:34:43,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
13:34:43,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:34:43,606 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) started (with errors) in 2831ms - Started 235 of 285 services (11 services failed or missing dependencies, 62 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
13:34:43,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment fwd-PMAP.war (runtime-name: fwd-PMAP.war) in 43ms
13:34:43,914 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015858: Undeployed "fwd-PMAP.war" (runtime-name: "fwd-PMAP.war")
13:34:43,915 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#arba" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#pmap" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP.realm (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./fwd-PMAP, service jboss.deployment.unit."fwd-PMAP.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#arba"
      service jboss.persistenceunit."fwd-PMAP.war#pmap"
```

And here's my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fwd</groupId>
    <artifactId>fwd-PMAP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>

        <restlet.version>2.3.4</restlet.version>
        <jackson.version>2.7.1</jackson.version>
        <groovy.version>2.4.5</groovy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3cp0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CSV file reader utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Copy POJO to POJO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Restlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Persistence file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <!-- FWD Connection -->
    <persistence-unit name="pmap" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.fwd.pmap.domain.Campaign</class>
        <class>com.fwd.pmap.domain.Employer</class>
        <class>com.fwd.pmap.domain.ISP</class>
        <class>com.fwd.pmap.domain.Ward</class>
        <class>com.fwd.pmap.domain.PMAPEtrekWorking</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx;databaseName=PMAP" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
        </properties>

     </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="arba" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.fwd.pmap.domain.PMAPEtrekWorking</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx;databaseName=PMAP" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

[Project Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm7f5.jpg)

Strange thing is when I deploy the WAR file on home machine (with local SQL Server instance), it is working fine. This error happens only when I am in the office.

Hope some kind souls can help me out.

Comment: Your log say's you are missing `PMAPEtrekWorking` in your classpath add that `package`

Comment: @subburoyal PMAPEtrekWorking is one of the POJO classes within my project. I've edited my post to include screenshot of my project layout, please take a look.

Comment: by seeing your error log `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fwd.pmap.domain.PMAPEtrekWorking` which means there is missing `jar` or `package` in your classpath, try to `clean build (mvn clean install)` your project and redeploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing (mvn clean install) solve the error. Found out that I was developing on JRE instead of JDK, that's why all the builds are having issue. Thanks @subburoyal